# Displaying data for logged user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have model called AdresModels, this is it:

```
namespace App_User.Models
{
public class AdresContext: DbContext
{
        public AdresContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles {get; set;}
        public DbSet<AdresModels> AdresModel { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RachunekModels> RachunekModel { get; set; } 
}


[Table("Adres")]
public class AdresModels
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int AdresID { get; set;}
public virtual int  UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual UserProfile User {get; set;}
    public string Miejscowosc { get; set; }
    public string Nr_domu { get; set; }
    public string Ulica { get; set; }
    public string Nr_mieszkania { get; set; }


}

}
```

Than i have view:

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Miejscowosc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nr_domu)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ulica)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nr_mieszkania)
    </td>
```

Now i want to display only this particular data in view where UserName == logged user.
I don't know where exactly i need to make changes to make it work.

I have one more question.

I have AdresModels and RachunekModels in RachunekModels i have foreign key from AdresModels, and i want to relate logged UserID with Adres, and than display data from Rachunek for logged user.

```
public class RachunekContext : DbContext
{
        public RachunekContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles {get; set;}
        public DbSet<AdresModels> AdresModel { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RachunekModels> RachunekModel { get; set; } 
}
[Table("Rachunek")]
public class RachunekModels
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int RachunekID { get; set;}

public virtual int AdresID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AdresID")]
public virtual AdresModels Adreses { get; set; }

}
```

I realy dont know how to relate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know where exactly i need to make changes to make it work.

In your controller action which is responsible for querying the model. That's where you should apply a filter to your query in order to retrieve only the elements that match this criteria:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string loggedUser = User.Identity.Name;
    var model = db.AdresModel.Where(x => x.User.UserName == loggedUser).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: But i add one more question later.

Comment: @z48o0, if you have other questions please start a new thread. Do not use a single thread to ask multiple questions as this is creating lots of noise and is not the way StackOverflow is intended to be used.